# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools.libmilstoragepython'の解決方法についてご教授ください。

Tags: python

Swiftを使ってiOSのアプリを開発したく、Udemyの一番人気のSwiftコースを受講しました。２〜３年前に配信された内容ですので、同じように書き込んだプログラムが正常に動作しないことが多いですが、それも勉強と思って試行錯誤しながら、正常に動作するように頑張っているところです。

講義内容がYouTubeにありました。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s44AEbM0jsI

Caffe ModelをCoreML Readable Modelに変換するために、Pythonでスクリプトを作成しました。（別ファイル。convert-script.py）
python convert-script.pyを実行すると、以下のようなエラーが出ますが、何が、問題でしょうか？
PCはM1 iMac 2021, macOS Venture13.2
python 3.11.1

(追記)coremltools
pip install -U coremltoolsを実行し、以下の結果となりました。
Successfully installed coremltools-6.1 mpmath-1.2.1 lumpy-1.24.1
packaging-23.0 protobuf-3.20.3 simply-1.11.1 tqdm-4.64.1

よろしくお願いします。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/略/Flower Classification/convert-script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import coremltools
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
    from . import converters
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import libsvm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/libsvm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _libsvm_converter, _libsvm_util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/libsvm/_libsvm_converter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from coremltools.models import _METADATA_SOURCE, _METADATA_VERSION
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/models/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import ml_program
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/models/ml_program/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import compression_utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/models/ml_program/compression_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from coremltools.converters.mil.frontend.milproto.load import \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/milproto/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .load import load
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/milproto/load.py", line 21, in <module>
    from coremltools.libmilstoragepython import _BlobStorageReader as BlobReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools.libmilstoragepython'
```

[image]

Comment: 「２〜３年前に配信された内容ですので、同じように書き込んだプログラムが正常に動作しないことが多い」であれば、Udemy講座のフォーラムに解決策があったりしませんか？またその講座の講師に質問することは出来ませんか？

Comment: convert-script.py の内容を質問に追記いただきたいです。また、PCやPython環境の説明も質問に追記してください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Udemy講座のフォーラム内でも探してみます。ネットで検索し対応してきましたが、今回のpythonについては、解決策を探すことができなかったため、ここを利用させてもらっています。convert-script.py の内容については、質問の中に貼り付けたプログラムが全ての内容になります。PCやPython環境の説明については質問に追記します。 –

Comment: こんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[Cannot import Identical Github Fork of Python CoreMLTools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73422260/9014308)

Comment: 講義内容がYouTubeにありましたので、質問に追記しました。

Comment: 参考記事ありがとうございます。記事の指摘通り進めることができれば解決できるかもしれません。しかし、私の現在のレベルにはかなりハードルが高そうなので、もう少し知識を蓄えてから挑戦します。UdemyのQ&Aにも今回のセクションは時代遅れのプログラムであり、正常に動作することができないような記載が多くあり、生徒から不満の投稿が多くありました。なかなか難解なセクションのようです。

Comment: coremltoolsはインストール済だが該当のエラーが発生する、ということでしょうか？（モジュールは https://github.com/apple/coremltools でしょうか？Udemyコースのコードが古いのであればモジュールインストール時にバージョン指定が必要な可能性がありますね。）

Comment: coremltoolsについて、質問に追記しました。ご確認よろしくお願いします。